# MAC - edit hosts file in bash script

Tags: bash

I have some VM stuff set up in my mamp instance, I'm using wp-cli in a bash to install wordpress instances, I wanted to add to this script a command to edit the hosts file based on a var.

```
sudo echo -e "127.0.0.1\timtest\n" >> /etc/hosts

-bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/82278/12892) to "How do I use sudo to redirect output to a location I don't have permission to write to?" from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `>>` gets associated with the `sudo` command, not with the `echo` command you're trying to run. You run echo with root perms, but the shell associates the `>>` with the sudo, no special perms.

I'd try it more like:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo -e "127.0.0.1\timtest\n" >> /etc/hosts'
```

(with a test run as sudo bash -c 'echo -e "127.0.0.1\timtest\n" >> /etc/hosts.new' for testing)